# java log4j12 writing to file but not able to see the file on disk

Tags: java, centos, log4j, slf4j

I am using slf4j + slf4j-log4j12 + log4j1.2.16 in my production setup.

I am facing a strange issue where in log4j is trying to write to the disk using CountingQuiteWriter and is able to write to the disk using java.io.FileOutputStream but file is not visible on disk.

Further debugging the issue, i am seeing that fd(file descriptor) used by the file handle is in deleted state.

l-wx------ 1 root root 64 Dec  1 19:07 165 -> */activemqlog.txt (deleted)

*- not showing the actual path due to stringent rules.

Comment: i) are you sure you have permission to see the file ii) are you sure there is no process running in the background that is cleaning your log files?

Comment: @Mil4n yes looking into that part only..if some body else is clearing the files.. as the inode entry remains but there is no visible file.

Comment: @Mil4n Is there a way in linux to find out the process Id  of process who deleted the file?